# Putting `self` into an `Arc` in Rust

Tags: rust

I have a Rust struct with a method that is designed to parallelise over multiple threads. Each thread needs to access that struct. So naturally I want to put it into an `Arc`. However I can't work out a way to do this.

Here's a simplified example:

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc};
use std::thread;
struct Foo {
    field: usize
}
impl Foo {
    fn parallel(&self){
        let arc = Arc::new(&self);
        for i in 1..5 {
            let arc = Arc::clone(&arc);
            thread::spawn(move || {
                i + arc.field
            });
        }
    } 
}
```

And the compiler says:

```rust
    fn parallel(&self){
                ^^^^^ this data with an anonymous lifetime `'_`...
        let arc = Arc::new(&self);
                           ^^^^^ ...is captured here...
            thread::spawn(move || {
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ...and is required to live as long as `'static` here
`self` has an anonymous lifetime `'_` but it needs to satisfy a `'static` lifetime requirement
```

So it would seem that I'm actually not *allowed* to put `self` into an `Arc` (not quite sure why, though).

I've also tried cloning `self` but that gives the same error:

```rust
impl Foo {
    fn parallel(&self){
        let clone = self.clone();
        let arc = Arc::new(&clone);
        for i in 1..5 {
            let arc = Arc::clone(&arc);
            thread::spawn(move || {
                i + arc.field
            });
        }
    } 
}
```

```rust
    fn parallel(&self){
                ^^^^^ this data with an anonymous lifetime `'_`...
        let clone = self.clone();
                         ^^^^^ ...is captured here...
            thread::spawn(move || {
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ...and is required to live as long as `'static` here
`self` has an anonymous lifetime `'_` but it needs to satisfy a `'static` lifetime requirement
```

Similar things happen if I try to move the `clone` into the `Arc`, or if I remove the `move` in front of the closure.

What is going on here, and how can I fix it? Also, in general, is there any way to do this: ie putting `self` into an Arc, where `self` is a struct?

Comment: You should put `Foo`, not `&Foo`, into `Arc`. `Arc` can not magically extend the lifetime of what is already a reference with a limited lifetime.

Comment: I still get this error with `let clone = self.clone(); let arc = Arc::new(clone);` though.

Comment: @Migwell That seems fine to me: <https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b3e98680849a344987ec14ace826dbdb>

Comment: Ah yes the key to that solution was deriving the `Clone` trait. Not sure why I was able to clone without it, but anyway.

Comment: If you don't worry about diverging copies of your type, there's no real question anyway. Cloning isn't suitable for all cases.

Comment: @Migwell If you don't derive `Clone` for the type, you end up copying the reference rather than the object itself due to the way method lookup works in Rust.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you put `self` or `&self` in the arc, you have to take it back at the end of the function.

It means you can't let it to the other threads.

The [crossbeam](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/0.8.1/crossbeam/fn.scope.html) crate includes a facility to deal with exactly this: ensure the threads release what you gave them:

> Creates a new scope for spawning threads.
>
> All child threads that haven’t been manually joined will be
> automatically joined just before this function invocation ends. If all
> joined threads have successfully completed, Ok is returned with the
> return value of f. If any of the joined threads has panicked, an Err
> is returned containing errors from panicked threads.

Example:

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc};
use crossbeam::thread;
struct Foo {
    field: usize
}
impl Foo {
    fn parallel(&self){
        let arc = Arc::new(&self);
        for i in 1..5 {
            let arc = Arc::clone(&arc);
            thread::scope(|s| {
                s.spawn(|_| {
                    i + arc.field
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, it looks like crossbeam (and Rayon, which wraps crossbeam) provides lots and lots of ways to solve this. Rayon's `for_each_with()` seems to solve this in a different and easy way, too.

Comment: Yes, when you want to do parallel computation, it's a good idea to go the easy Rayon way. It often turns out it's hard to go much faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap `Foo` in `Arc` and define methods for `Arc<Foo>`

```rust
use std::{sync::Arc, time::Duration};
use tokio::task::JoinSet;

struct Foo {
    field: usize
}

impl Foo {
    async fn add(&self, n: usize) {
        println!("calculation {} + {n}...", self.field);
        tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
        println!("{} + {n} = {}", self.field, self.field + n);
    }

    async fn parallel(self: Arc<Self>){
        let mut set = JoinSet::new();
        for i in 1..5 {
            let foo = self.clone();
            set.spawn(async move {
                foo.add(i).await
            });
        }

        // wait for tasks...
        while let Some(_) = set.join_next().await {}
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    println!("Start");
    let foo = Foo { field: 23 };
    foo.add(10).await;
    // foo.parallel().await; // error: Foo should be wrapped in Arc
    println!("Non parallel done");

    let foo = Arc::new(foo);
    {
        let foo = foo.clone();
        tokio::spawn(async move { foo.parallel().await });
    }
    foo.parallel().await;

    println!("End");
}
```